# Using ShareLink in SwiftUI to create item text with URL link formatted for both the Message app and email

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-sharelink, sharelink

My need is to use ShareLink to allow the user to send formatted email or text message including a URL link. My SwiftUI code looks like:

```
    ShareLink(
        item: itemText,
        subject: Text("Message from app user"),
        preview: SharePreview("Link",image: "AppIcon")) {
        Label(message, systemImage:  "square.and.arrow.up")
    }
```

where I'm generating `itemText` from `itemText(link: URL)` (I've trimmed the string I'm using to just the basics):

```
    func shareItemMessage(link: URL) -> String {
        return
            "Please join me on our app\n\n"
            + "Tap on [link](\(link)) to accept my invitation (link: \(link)).\n\n"
    }

    func itemText(link: URL) -> (some Transferable)? {
        // The `available` condition is needed because only in iOS 16.1 does AttributedString conform to Transferable.
        if #available(iOS 16.1, *) {
            // The AttributedString options below enable inclusion of whitespace in the text formatting.
            // See also https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/markdown-linebreaks-are-ignored.2367417/
            return try? AttributedString(markdown: shareItemMessage(link: link),
                options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(
                    allowsExtendedAttributes: false,
                    interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace,
                    failurePolicy: .returnPartiallyParsedIfPossible,
                    languageCode: nil
                ))
        } else {
            return shareItemMessage(link: link)
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the markdown gets stripped out when the user chooses the message app. Example:

[image]

And when they use an email, I get two links. Example:

[image]

Note that I've generated the image examples above running on an iPhone with > iOS 16.1, so it's using the AttributedString formatting for both the message and email.

Has anyone come up with a better way to do this? i.e., to use ShareLink to send a text email or message with a link?